# date based on yes or no value in another column

Tags: excel-formula

Column G will either be blank or have a yes or no in it. Column L has a date value in it. IF column G has a yes in it I want column R to subtract 9 months from the date in column L. If column G is blank or no I want Column R to remain blank.

Comment: Kindly share to us what you have tried so far.  The community would be more willing to help you if you can show any attempt to solve this concern.

Comment: I had =Date(YEAR(L13),MONTH(L13)-9,DAY(L13)-0) as my formula but was unsure on how to calculate for the yes/no valure in column G.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this formula in column R (the below formula will work for row 2):

```
=IF(G2="Yes",DATE(YEAR(L2),MONTH(L2)-9,DAY(L2)),"")
```

Note that the adjustment of 9 months might look a bit odd. If your date is, say, 30 November 2018, the formula is supposed to return 30 Feb 2018. However, since no date exists, it will instead return 02 March 2018 *(which is Excel's way of saying as two days after 28 February 2018)*.

Comment: When I enter this formula it gives me back an error message "you've entered too many arguments for this function." When I click on OK it highlights "" at the end.

Comment: @user2644122, the formula is missing a closing parenthesis. Try this instead: `=IF(G2="Yes",DATE(YEAR(L2),MONTH(L2)-9,DAY(L2)),"")`